# Why I can't connect the eth0 with putty?

Tags: linux, apache, centos6, httpd.conf

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:20:08:46:CD:C7
          inet addr:172.26.26.60  Bcast:172.26.26.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::420:8ff:fe46:cdc7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:1577 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:141738 (138.4 KiB)  TX bytes:215770 (210.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:165

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:81:8C:00:F4:F2
          inet addr:172.26.26.37  Bcast:172.26.26.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::481:8cff:fe00:f4f2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:16216 (15.8 KiB)  TX bytes:8921 (8.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:164
```

the server is a LAMP environment. I use DHCP mode to add a eth1, ifconfig shows as the above. and I can't connect to the eth0 with ip 172.26.26.60  I can only connect to the eth1 with 172.26.26.37 with putty.   is set but not working.

### I want to know why I can't connect to the 172.26.26.60?

edit:
route -n 
it outputs like below:

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

172.26.26.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0

172.26.26.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1

0.0.0.0         172.26.26.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1

Comment: Are the ports connected to different lans that just happen to share the same private subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Ssh server config. It might only be listening on one address. `netstat -an | grep 22 | grep LISTEN` should show you which address you're listening on.

Answer (score 0):

Step 0 - ping, check cables, etc.

Step 1 - check if sshd is really listening on 0.0.0.0. Otherwise it's only available on the corresponding interface.

Step 2 - check iptables -nvL

Step 3 - check route -n

Comment: route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.26.26.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
172.26.26.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         172.26.26.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
I use route -n it shows like this.